# Cooperation for cross-server celery workers

Tags: python, celery

My use case: 
(celery task A runs on server A while celery task B runs on server B)

**taskA**(on server A) -> invoke and wait **taskB** finish(on server B) -> **taskA** on (server A) continue with result from taskB

pseudo code:

on server A

```
@task    
def taskA():
  remoteTask = current_app.send_task("taskB", exchange="xxx", routing_key="serverB")
  result = t.get()
  # process result
```

on server B

```
@task
def taskB():
  # do something
  return result
```

The code obviously violated ["Avoid launching synchronous subtasks"](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) rule mentioned in Celery official guidance. And I can see deadlock warnings from the console.

So, I tried to rewrite the code in **subtask** style by **signature** method and **or** operator

```
@task
def taskA()  
  remoteTask = signature("taskB", exchange="xxx", routing_key="serverB")
  followingTask = signature("taskAA", exchange="xxx", routing_key="serverA")
  chain = remoteTask | followingTask
  return chain()

@task
def taskAA(result)
  # process result
```

The deadlock warning went away, but the code seems not that clear.

Is there any better solution? Or did I missed something?